# Use jquery show() and hide() on a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using php codeigniter for my project

I try this code but its not working to show and hide my form please refer code bellow

Js File

```
<script>
    $('#search_option_4').on('change',function() {
        if( $(this).val()==="Sale") {
            $("#Sale_form").show()
        }
        else {
            $("#Sale_form").hide()
        }
    });
</script>
```

Form file

```
<div class="wrap-search">
    <div class="container">
        <ul name="search_option_4" id="search_option_4" class="menu-onmap tabbed-selector">
            {options_values_li_4}
            <?php if(config_db_item('property_subm_disabled')==FALSE):  ?>
            <li class="list-property-button"><a href="{myproperties_url}">{lang_Listproperty}</a></li>
            <?php endif;?>
        </ul>
<!-- FORM -->
        <div id="Sale_form" class="search-form hidden">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <input id="search_option_smart" type="text" class="span6" placeholder="{lang_CityorCounty}" />
                <select id="search_option_2" class="span3 selectpicker" placeholder="{options_name_2}">
                    {options_values_2}
                </select>
</div>
```

{options_value_li_4}
(Value contains Sale,Rent,Commercial)

Thank you

Comment: `<ul>` is not input type. so you cant bind `change` value with it. user `select-option` instead

Comment: ul with `li` don't have `onchange` event. you need to use `select` for that. you can bind `click` on `ul` and `li`

Comment: it isn't wrapped in a `document.ready` either

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution

```
<script>
$('#search_option_4 li').on('click',function() {
  if( $(this).val()==="Sale") {
    $("#Sale_form").show()
  } else {
    $("#Sale_form").hide()
  }
}); 
</script>
```

Click event should be triggered from li instead of ul `#search_option_4`.

**Or Second method**

```
<script>
$('#search_option_4').on('click', 'li', function() {
  if( $(this).val()==="Sale") {
    $("#Sale_form").show()
  } else {
    $("#Sale_form").hide()
  }
}); 
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('#search_option_4').on('click',function() {
        if( $(this).val()==="Sale") {
            $("#Sale_form").show()
        }
        else {
            $("#Sale_form").hide()
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It would improve the quality of your answer if you would include some details.  How does your answer solve the problem, what would help OP understand why he couldn't get it working etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback will surely work on it, sir!
btw in his query instead of "on change" event "click" event should be used that's the reason why he is getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Propiedad del modal.

```
$("#Sale_form").modal.('show');
$("#Sale_form").modal.('hide')
```

Respuesta:

```
<script>
    $('#search_option_4').on('click', 'li', function() {
      if( $(this).val()==="Sale") {
        $("#Sale_form").modal.('show')
      } else {
        $("#Sale_form").modal.('hide')
      }
    }); 
    </script>
```